# GLImageProcessing in xcode to show DICOM files

Tags: opengl-es

On another forum based site I was informed that the OpenGL-es in xcode could display DICOM images - could anyone verify this as I have tried with no success. Does anyone have any suggestions of sample code - i need something similar to GLImageProcessing sample code.

thanks in advance

rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is agnostic to image file formats. It really boils down to extracting per-pixel RGBA values (or something similar) from your image and then using glTexImage2D to create the texture.

You might want to search for libraries reading pixel data from JPEG first, as DICOM seems to store images in that format (according to Wikipedia):

> Pixel data can be compressed using a
>   variety of standards, including JPEG,
>   JPEG Lossless, JPEG 2000, and
>   Run-length encoding (RLE). LZW (zip)
>   compression can be used for the whole
>   data set (not just the pixel data) but
>   this is rarely implemented.

Comment: thanks for the reply.... makes sense... now having spent a further 5 days on how to extract the pixel data from a dicom file I am no closer. However you are right DICOM files do store the pixel data in a jpeg format - feeling 1 step closer.. just need someone elses help to get the data out.